# Best Practice for Storing Login Credentials in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript, electric-clojure

In `ClojureScript`, I initially stored login credentials and authorization information in an atom state. However, I encountered a persistent issue where the atom state gets flushed upon page refresh, leading me to explore alternative storage solutions.

Previous Approach:

```clj
(set! (.-cookie js/document) {:customer true :supplier false :admin false :user "test" :company "company-test"})
```

Questions:

- I'm seeking recommendations for a more reliable way to store login credentials persistently on the client side without losing data upon page refresh.
- Is storing sensitive data such as login credentials in cookies a secure approach? Are there potential vulnerabilities or better alternatives that offer enhanced security?

Comment: Storing a map with `:admin false` on the client-side is a bad idea
- I can just toggle the flag on my end and become admin.  If you want to
  make it stateless, sign or encrypt (e.g. JWS/JWE) -- or keep the state
  on the server.  I think this is an X-Y-problem.  While the generic
  cljs answer is to store it in cookie/localstore/..., OP wants to have
  a persistent session against electric/hyperfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt (hard to crack, and cannot tamper)
or encode (easy to crack, and cannot tamper)
your data.

On the clientside in localstorage, for example, instead of storing actual credentials, consider using authentication tokens (like JWTs). The server issues a token upon successful login, and the client stores this token. The token is then used for subsequent requests to authenticate the user.

The token has all the info, you send it over the wire with each request, the token is read by the server and server confirms it is legit, and knows who is doing the actions.

To create such a token,

1. User Authentication
   Initial Login: The user logs in with their credentials (username and password).
   Server Validation: The server validates these credentials against the stored user data (usually in a database).
2. Token Generation
   Create Token: Upon successful login, the server generates a token. This can be a random string or a structured token like JWT (JSON Web Token).
   Include Necessary Information: For JWT, include claims like user ID, issued time, and expiration time. Be cautious not to include sensitive information.
   Sign the Token: If using JWT, sign the token with a secret key. This ensures that the token can't be tampered with.
3. Send it over (https) to the client
4. Send back [from client] to server on every request
5. Have server check the expiration time on the token and if coming up soon,
6. Refresh the token for an uninterrupted experience
7. When expired, redirect to login

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to store credentials (login+password+whatever else) on the frontend side is not to store them. You store a secure cookie with the right session ID, not the credentials themselves. If the cookie is not a session one, it's a permanent one. Such a cookie also has an expiration date.
Of course, that requires you to have a backend that can store all the session information.

I wouldn't call the map in your code block "credentials", it's more like "user properties" or something like that. They shouldn't be persisted anywhere except for the server, and on every page load those details should be retrieved again using the session ID stored in the cookie. Note that you don't need to do anything on the client side to make cookies work - it's all done on the backend.

Comment: When I check the session ID, it's also changed when the page refreshed. I can match the session ID and the details. But I'll lose the session ID when I refreshed page.  For instance, there is  [ChatExtended](https://electric.hyperfiddle.net/user.demo-chat-extended!%43hat%45xtended) example. The session ID changes on every page refresh. Can you enlighten me more?

Comment: Alas, not really. That page is like a dozen different technologies mixed together, when you take into account the server as well. What I can tell for certain is that that session ID on the page is not the session ID that I'm talking about, and that the cookies aren't used in a way they're commonly used. Another thing I can say is that, IMO, you should avoid technologies as high level as Electric/Hyperfiddle unless you also know how it all works underneath. Otherwise you'll end up stumbling in the dark solving incessant pesky tech problems.

Comment: @DustinGetz I separate them. "Browser-native API" is an umbrella term that doesn't really mean anything useful in this context. The relevant parts are DOM, cookies, HTTP and WS requests, basic HTTP auth. Same with Ring - Ring itself is just an abstraction layer that the example doesn't even expose. So we actually have Electric on top of Ring on top of Jetty, plus routing (open `/auth` in incognito and enter credentials - "Page not found" follows), and of course Clojure itself.

Comment: fair enough – Ring 1.11 adds websocket support, it officially released two days ago, this will allow us to drop the jetty http server boilerplate which appears to be the crux of your objection here (needing to understand how to serve a websocket which forced a drop to lower API since ring previously couldn't do it)